# Creating model for data binding and class with methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I would want to know what is the best way to create a model for data binding but also a class with methods with the same name in asp.net web forms.

So my model:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

But I would also want class Movie to have some methods.

Comment: OK. You can do it quiet easily and the above looks fine. Are you using any architecture or pattern like `Three-Tier` or `N-Tier` to use the above?

Comment: Maybe use something like `public List<Movie> getMovies(){. . .}` and query your database inside the method?